# align text and equations in columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, vertical-alignment, align

I have a `beamer` frame consisting of two columns (top aligned) using the `[T]` option. The second column contains a `align` equation block. Even though I am using the `[T]` option the column containing the equation will *not* align with the text in the left column. When a put a line of text just before the equation the alignment works fine. So what am I missing ?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1$}}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \column{0.4\textwidth}
        Transverse MO Kerr effect
        {\tiny [Zvezdin, Modern Magnetooptics, IOP 1999]}
        \column{0.6\textwidth}
        %\centering test
        \begin{align*}
        r_p(M) &= r^0_p\left(1+i\rho_p(M)\right)\\
        \rho_p(M) &=\frac{-ir_p^0\epsilon_g(M)/\epsilon_z\sin\varphi}{2(\eta^2-\sin^2\varphi)^{1/2}}\\
            [r_s(M) &= r^0_s\quad\eta =n/n_\mathrm{inc}]\\
            \delta_p &= \frac{I(M)-I_0}{I_0} = \highlight{2\IM(\rho_p)} %\quad \textcolor{red}{\textbf{\only on lossy MO materials}}
        \end{align*}\par
        \centering$\color{red}\Rightarrow$ \textcolor{red}{\textbf{only on lossy MO materials}}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \column{0.4\textwidth}
        Transverse MO Kerr effect
        {\tiny [Zvezdin, Modern Magnetooptics, IOP 1999]}
        \column{0.6\textwidth}
        \centering test
        \begin{align*}
        r_p(M) &= r^0_p\left(1+i\rho_p(M)\right)\\
        \rho_p(M) &=\frac{-ir_p^0\epsilon_g(M)/\epsilon_z\sin\varphi}{2(\eta^2-\sin^2\varphi)^{1/2}}\\
            [r_s(M) &= r^0_s\quad\eta =n/n_\mathrm{inc}]\\
            \delta_p &= \frac{I(M)-I_0}{I_0} = \highlight{2\IM(\rho_p)} %\quad \textcolor{red}{\textbf{\only on lossy MO materials}}
        \end{align*}\par
        \centering$\color{red}\Rightarrow$ \textcolor{red}{\textbf{only on lossy MO materials}}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because there is `\abovedisplayskip`. make it zero or even negative only there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`align` will have `\abovedisplayskip` above the its top. You have to get rid of it. Plus since making it zero will bring the equation in the next line (display equation!) making

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}
```

will do the job. Further, you need to add a `\par in

```
{\tiny [Zvezdin, Modern Magnetooptics, IOP 1999]\par}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{$\displaystyle #1$}}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \column[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        Transverse MO Kerr effect
        {\tiny [Zvezdin, Modern Magnetooptics, IOP 1999]\par}   %% you need a \par here
        \column[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}
        %\centering test
        \begin{align*}
        r_p(M) &= r^0_p\left(1+i\rho_p(M)\right)\\
        \rho_p(M) &=\frac{-ir_p^0\epsilon_g(M)/\epsilon_z\sin\varphi}{2(\eta^2-\sin^2\varphi)^{1/2}}\\
            [r_s(M) &= r^0_s\quad\eta =n/n_\mathrm{inc}]\\
            \delta_p &= \frac{I(M)-I_0}{I_0} = \highlight{2\IM(\rho_p)} %\quad \textcolor{red}{\textbf{\only on lossy MO materials}}
        \end{align*}\par
        \centering$\color{red}\Rightarrow$ \textcolor{red}{\textbf{only on lossy MO materials}}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. However I didn't get why setting `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}` doesn't quite work? Also why exactly do I need a `\par` in the first column?

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem `\par` before closing the group, as in `{\tiny <text>\par}` is to guarantee that the correct `\baselineskip` will be applied for `<text>`. You won't notice any effect in your example code, since the text doesn't span more than one line.

Comment: I have another question. Even though the columns align on the top, they don't get placed at the top of the frame ?

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem For that you have to use `\begin{frame}[t]`.

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem With `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}` the equation comes to the next line. To remove the empty line at the top, you need `\baselineskip`.